# ajax search box with xml database

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to create a live search box on my website. I have an XML-file for a database. I've got the JavaScript part done, but I am a newbie at PHP and have some issues with this code I found on w3schools. My question is how do I modify the following code so that I only get the value of the "name" tag?

PHP code:

```
 <?php
 $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
 $xmlDoc->load("links.xml");
 $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');
 //get the q parameter from URL
 $q=$_GET["q"];
 //lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
 if (strlen($q) > 0)
 {
 $hint="";
 for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++)
 {
 $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
 $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
 if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1)
 {
 //find a link matching the search text
 if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q))
 {
 if ($hint=="")
 {
 $hint="<a href='" . 
 $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
 "' target='_blank'>" . 
 $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
 }
 else
 {
 $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" . 
 $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
 "' target='_blank'>" . 
 $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
  }
 }
}
}
}


// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint were found
 // or to the correct values
 if ($hint == "")
 {
 $response="no suggestion";
 }
 else
 {
 $response=$hint;
 }
 //output the response
 echo $response;
 ?>
```

XML:

```
<books>

   <book>
     <name>Harry Potter</name>
     <quantity> 50 </quantity>
     <price>19.90</price>
   </book>


   <book>
     <name>Casino Royale</name>
     <quantity> 50 </quantity>
     <price>12.99</price>
   </book>


   <book>
     <name>The Great Gatsby</name>
     <quantity> 40 </quantity>
     <price>14.90</price>
   </book>

</books>
```

Thank you in advance for your answers! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Not sure why javascript is tagged here, this seems like a purely php and xml question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you would do it:

```
<?php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");
$books = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("book");

//get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q) > 0) {
    $hint = "";

    foreach ($books as $book) {
        $name = $book->getElementsByTagName("name")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $price = $book->getElementsByTagName("price")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $quantity = $book->getElementsByTagName("quantity")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        echo "$name - $price - $quantity<br/>";
    }

}
```

That will print out the `$name`, `$price`, and `$quantity` from the xml file for each book.

Comment: I tried your version of the code, but this code spits all of the data from the XML-file directly on to the website. I want this to happen only when the user starts typing inside the search box.

Comment: @JavaApprentice so the key points are the method calls to get the data. That is what you were looking for. This example shows how to get the xml data. Now you will have to add that to your code that handles the search box. So the for loop in your code can be replaced with the foreach call in my example. Then you can update the code to use my example for getting the title, price and/or quantity.